# how to check if a given email address actually exist in c#?

Tags: c#, email

I am building a C# application where users creat an account and type their email address,
I know how to validate it with Regular expression, what I am having truble with is how to check if that email actually exist?
i.e.   lilush@gmail.com  --> is there such email address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

The only way to check this is to send an email to that address and make sure that you send a link that needs to be clicked to activate the account. There is no other way to check if an email is correct

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [EmailVerify.NET](http://www.emailverify.net/)

> EmailVerify.NET is a powerful Microsoft .NET software component that verifies e-mail addresses with various tools, including:
>
> - Advanced syntax verification, according to IETF standards (RFC 2821 and RFC 2822, among others)
>
>   - DNS validations, including MX record(s) lookup
>   - Disposable e-mail address (DEA) validation
>   - SMTP connection and availability checking
>   - Mailbox existence checking, with greylisting and temporary unavailability support
>   - Catch-all testing

Answer (score 3):

There's only one way to do that: Send an email containing a (unique, of course) link to the address, and ask the user to click the link.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to be really fancy you could embed an image in the email as-well.  When your server detects that the image was downloaded then you know they opened the email.  This also removes the need for the clicking a link thing which many people either don't trust or it doesn't work. Just a thought.

Comment: Many e-mail clients block images, simply because this sort of tracking is so prevalent.